# How to optimize comparing combinations in a python list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, math, combinations

I have a list of 16,000 lists. Each sublist contains a tuple and a score, like this:

```
mylist = [
[('only','one','time'),10.54],
[('one','time'),3.21],
[('red','hot','chili','peppers'),0.223],
[('red','hot','chili'),1.98]
]
```

My goal is to iterate through combinations in mylist and remove any element when a **superset** or **subset** is detected. The element to be removed is based on the lowest score between the two. So in this example, I want to remove

```
[('one','time'),3.21],
[('red','hot','chili','peppers'),0.223]
```

because ('one','time') is a *subset* of ('only','one','time') and between the two, ('one','time') has the lowest score 10.54>3.21.
('red','hot','chili','peppers') is a *superset* of ('red','hot','chili') and between the two, 0.223<1.98

My initial solution was a brute force - get every possible combination from the list choose 2, then compare the tuples for subsets using the all() function, then drop the items with the min() score.
This performs poorly due the to number of combinations to search:

```
    from itertools import combinations
    removelist = []
    for x,y in combinations(mylist,2):
        if (all(word in x[0] for word in y[0]) or all(word in y[0] for word in x[0])):
            smallest = min([x,y],key=itemgetter(1))
            removelist.append(smallest)
    removelist = set(removelist)
    outlist = [x for x in mylist if x not in removelist]
    return outlist
```

returns:

```
outlist = [
[('only','one','time'),10.54],
[('red','hot','chili'),1.98]
]
```

So for a list of ~16,000 sublists, this would be roughly:

```
combinations = n! / (r! * (n-r)!)  
combinations = 16,000! / (2! * (15998)!)  
combinations = 16,000 * 15999 / 2
combinations = 127,992,000
```

Is there a smarter way to do this, reducing the 127 million items I need to check?

Comment: *I may have kept `('one','time')` if the score was higher, so it doesn't matter which element is the subset, only that the subset was detected* - in this case would you have dropped the `('only','one','time')` or kept both?

Comment: How many total distinct words are there?

Comment: Please describe the exact logic you want to implement. Preferably, show some code with your toy example.

Comment: @pault - i would have dropped the superset, only thing that matters is that the score is lower. made logic more clear and added code/library import

Comment: @MadPhysicist - there are 16,000 distinct tuples. each tuple is composed of words, of which there are 3900 distinct words (using a counter() function)

Comment: What to do with ties? I.e., a subset/superset pair with the same score?

Comment: @StefanPochmann - then the min() function will return the first element it sees, which is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a thousand times faster than yours. First I convert the word tuples to sets for simpler and faster subset checks, like @Alexander. Then I sort by set size, so I don't have to check for superset. (Because if |A| ≤ |B|, then the only way A is a superset of B is if it *is* B, in which case it is also a *subset* of B).

And then comes my main trick. Let's say we have the word set {'red','hot','chili'}, and we want to find the word sets of which it is a subset. Do we need to check all other (larger or equal-size) sets? No. It suffices to check only those sets that contain the word 'red'. Or only those with 'hot'. Or only those with 'chili'. Let's take the *rarest* word, i.e., the one in the fewest sets (in this case I'd guess 'chili').

I decided to call your lists "songs", makes it nice to talk about them.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def process_list_stefan(mylist):

    # Change to sets, attach the index, and sort by number of words (many to few)
    songs = [(i, set(words), score) for i, (words, score) in enumerate(mylist)]
    songs.sort(key=lambda song: -len(song[1]))

    # Check songs against others, identify the ones to remove
    remove = set()
    songs_with_word = defaultdict(list)
    for song in songs:
        i, words1, score1 = song
        # Pick the song's rarest word
        word = min(words1, key=lambda word: len(songs_with_word[word]))
        # Go through songs containing that word
        for j, words2, score2 in songs_with_word[word]:
            if words1 <= words2:
                # Lower score loses. In case of tie, lower index loses.
                remove.add(min((score1, i), (score2, j))[1])
        # Make this song available as superset candidate
        for word in words1:
            songs_with_word[word].append(song)

    # Apply the removals
    return [song for i, song in enumerate(mylist) if i not in remove]
```

**Update:** Actually, instead of just using the song's rarest word and going through all its "supersets" (sets containing that word), consider *all* words in the current song and use the *intersection* of their "supersets". In my testing with made up data, it's even faster by about factor 1.6:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def process_list_stefan(mylist):

    # Change to sets, attach the index, and sort by number of words (many to few)
    songs = [(i, set(words), score) for i, (words, score) in enumerate(mylist)]
    songs.sort(key=lambda song: -len(song[1]))

    # Helper: Intersection of sets
    def intersect(sets):
        s = next(sets).copy()
        for t in sets:
            s &= t
        return s

    # Check songs against others, identify the ones to remove
    remove = set()
    songs_with_word = defaultdict(set)
    for song in songs:
        i, words1, score1 = song
        for j in intersect(songs_with_word[word] for word in words1):
            # Lower score loses. In case of tie, lower index loses.
            remove.add(min((score1, i), (mylist[j][1], j))[1])
        # Make this song available as superset candidate
        for word in words1:
            songs_with_word[word].add(i)

    # Apply the removals
    return [song for i, song in enumerate(mylist) if i not in remove]
```

Comment: Marking Stefan's answer as correct due to a clear explanation, fastest run time (from 20 minutes to a few seconds on ~16,000 lists), and correct output of subsets + supersets based on highest score.

Comment: @tbrk Darn, I was hoping for less than a second :-). Can you also count the number of set comparisons in my first solution, so we can see how much that reduced from your 127 million? I.e., `ctr += 1` right before `if words1 <= words2:`.

Comment: Sure Stefan, I really appreciate the help. I put a counter = 0 before "for song in songs:", counter +=1 before "if words1 <= words2", and returned 1,345,928 checks down from 127 million (100 factor reduction!)

Comment: @tbrk Thanks. On my made up test data it was even better, but that was uniform random data, so no "hot" words appearing in many sets.

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new list that retains the original scores but converts the tuples of words into sets for faster comparisons and set membership testing.

Enumerate through each set of words and scores in this new list and compare against all remaining sets and scores.  Using sets, we can detect subsets via `s1.issubset(s2)` and supersets via `s1.issuperset(s2)`.

Once the subset/superset has been detected, we compare scores.  If the current record has a higher score, we mark the other for removal and then continue comparing against the remaining records.  Otherwise, we add the current index location to a set of indices to be subsequently removed and continue any remaining comparisons against this record.

Once we have processed all of the records, we use a conditional list comprehension to create a new list of all records to keep.

In terms of subset comparisons, worst case time complexity is O(n^2) / 2, which is still O(n^2).  Of course, each subset comparison has its own time complexity based on the number of unique words in each sublist.  This solution thus makes the same number of comparisons as the OP's `for x,y in combinations(mylist,2)` method, but the subset/superset comparisons are done using sets rather than lists.  As a result, this method should still be significantly faster.

```
def process_list(my_list):
    # Convert tuples to sets.
    my_sets = [(set(tuples), score) for tuples, score in my_list]

    idx_to_remove = set()
    for i, (subset1, score1) in enumerate(my_sets):
        for j, (subset2, score2) in enumerate(my_sets[(i + 1):], start=i + 1):
            if subset1.issubset(subset2) | subset1.issuperset(subset2):  
                # Subset/Superset detected.
                idx_to_remove.add(i if score1 < score2 else j)

    # Remove filtered items from list and return filtered list.
    return [tup for n, tup in enumerate(my_list) if n not in idx_to_remove]

# TEST CASES

# Case 1.
mylist = [
    [('only','one','time'), 10.54],
    [('one','time'), 3.21],
    [('red','hot','chili','peppers'), 0.223],
    [('red','hot','chili'), 1.98],
] 
>>> process_list(mylist)
[[('only', 'one', 'time'), 10.54], [('red', 'hot', 'chili'), 1.98]]

# Case 2.
# ('a', 'b', 'd') is superset of ('a', 'b') and has a lower score, so remove former.
# ('a', 'b') is a subset of ('a', 'b', 'c') and has a lower score, so remove former.
mylist = [[('a', 'b', 'c'), 3], [('a', 'b', 'd'), 1], [('a', 'b'), 2]]
>>> process_list(mylist)
[[('a', 'b', 'c'), 3]]

# Case 3.  Same items as Case 2, but different order.  Same logic as Case 2.
mylist = [[('a', 'b'), 2], [('a', 'b', 'c'), 3], [('a', 'b', 'd'), 1]]
>>> process_list(mylist)
[[('a', 'b', 'c'), 3]]

# Case 4.
# ('a', 'b', 'c') is a superset of ('a', 'b') and has a lower score, so remove former.
# ('d','c') is a subset of ('d','c','w') and has a lower score, so remove former.
mylist = [[('a', 'b'), 2], [('a', 'b', 'c'), 1], [('d','c','w'), 4], [('d','c'), 2]]
>>> process_list(mylist)
[[('a', 'b'), 2], [('d', 'c', 'w'), 4]]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205633/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-how-to-optimize-comparing-combinations-in-a-py).

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, I just found it strange that you talked complexity without pointing out your advantage. Btw, you could sort by set size and then drop the superset test.

Comment: I initially sorted by the length of the tuple and then by score, but I couldn't figure out how to make use of the sort.  The functions `.issubset()` and `issuperset()` first do a fast check the size of each set to avoid obvious cases (e.g. `s1.issubset(s2)` returns `False` if len(s1) > len(s2)`). So I don't believe doing a presort would actually result in any performance gain.

Comment: @Alexander If their example data is representative, i.e., the 16,000 tuples all have about two to four words, then very often s1 and s2 will have the same size and then that optimization won't apply. Also, the constant overhead of just *calling* the check might dwarf its actual execution. Try [this](https://repl.it/repls/WideChiefDeclarations). In any case I'm happy I thought of it because it enables my solution :-)

Comment: @Alexander One more thing: You'd probably better use `or` instead of `|`. Both for clarity (you're applying a bit operation to bools) and for speed (you always evaluate both operands, even if the first one is true).